# Best way to split a large method for click listener

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm, onclicklistener

After rebuilding my project, I get an error saying that one of my methods is too large, and it then directs me to a click listener. Does anyone know a good way of splitting the method or breaking it down? I honestly I have no idea on the recommended way to do this when all the connected strings (500+ within an RecyclerView and array) are related to the same item.

> Method too large

and

> e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation

```
        ibMap.setOnClickListener {
            when {
                tvTitle.text.toString() == "029" -> {
                    when {
                        isAppInstalled -> { // Intent to launch Google Maps if the standard package is already installed

                            val gmmIntentUri =
                                Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=Cardiff, United Kingdom")

                            val mapIntent =
                                Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)

                            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")

                            // Attempt to start an activity that can handle the Intent
                            mCtx.startActivity(mapIntent)
                        }
                        isLiteAppInstalled -> { // Intent to launch Google Maps Go if the lite package is already installed

                            val gmmIntentUri =
                                Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=Cardiff, United Kingdom")

                            val mapIntent =
                                Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)

                            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.mapslite")

                            mCtx.startActivity(mapIntent)
                        }
                        else -> { // Intent to launch Google Maps in web browser if neither of the above apps are installed

                            val str =
                                "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Cardiff,+United+Kingdom/"

                            // Attempt to start an activity that can handle the Intent
                            mCtx.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(str)))
                        }
                    }
                }

               // 500 more strings
            }
```

Comment: first, try to split the logic into many methods, second, you can make generic conditions in outer classes.

Comment: @MoustafEL-Saghier what do you mean by the logic? Bear in mind that this click event is inside a `ReyclerView` adapter.

Comment: the action you need to do depend on specific values

Comment: @MoustafEL-Saghier I don't know any better way of specifying those actions as I did follow a tutorial.

Comment: for example : `val mapIntent =
                                Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)

                            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")

                            // Attempt to start an activity that can handle the Intent
                            mCtx.startActivity(mapIntent)` I see it is the same code for `isAppInstalled ` and `isLiteAppInstalled ` why not set both in the same val check or outer method so u save about 6 - 9 lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of duplicate code even in this small sample. In general you should avoid copy pasting code blocks and instead extract them as separate method. First add it inside your RecyclerView adapter or wherever your onclick can reach:

```
fun launchMapIntent(locationName: String) {
    // determine package to open
    val mapPkg = when {
        isAppInstalled -> "com.google.android.apps.maps"
        isLiteAppInstalled -> "com.google.android.apps.mapslite"
        else -> null
    }
    val mapIntent = if(mapPkg != null) {
        // open app
        val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=$locationName")
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri).setPackage(mapPkg)
    } else {
        // fallback to browser
        val encLoc = Uri.encode(locationName)
        val str = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/$encLoc/"
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(str))
    }
    mCtx.startActivity(mapIntent)
}
```

Then you can clean up duplicate code from your onclick listener:

```
ibMap.setOnClickListener {
    when(tvTitle.text.toString()) {
        "029" -> launchMapIntent("Cardiff, United Kingdom")
        "030" -> launchMapIntent("other location...")
        // other cases
    }
}
```

Alternatively if all of your cases are opening the maps:

```
ibMap.setOnClickListener {
    val locationName = when(tvTitle.text.toString()) {
        "029" -> "Cardiff, United Kingdom"
        "030" -> "other location..."
        // other cases
    }
    launchMapIntent(locationName)
}
```

You could further optimize by making a `Map<Int, String>` with numbers as keys and location names as values instead of having a huge switch or somehow hold them in a database etc

Comment: How can I do the same thing for an Array? When I click `030` I want a popup menu to appear then I want the map intent to launch depending on whichever item from the popup menu that I click. I asked this in a [seperate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653676/how-to-use-custom-array-for-popup-menu)